# AngularJS and .htaccess: Google not indexing

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I built an AngularJS application and I'm using URLs **without #**.

Google doesn't index the partial pages (only included about.html here). This means Google **searches** for content of the partials **fail**.

I guess this has something to do with the **.htaccess** file and the **rewrite rules** for the Apache server. According to my information it is possible to let Google index all partials, even for a *single page application*.

I'm also using *Webmaster Tools* and get no errors with the **sitemap.xml**. All links and pages are accessible, only the *indexing/search* via Google doesn't work. Also crawling and rendering through the Webmaster Tools site seems to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**link on index.html**

```
<li data-ng-class="{ active: isActive('/about') }">
  <a id="about-link" href="/about" data-pjax>About</a>
</li>
```

**siteapp.js**

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode( true ).hashPrefix( '!' );

$routeProvider.
  when( "/overview", {
    title: 'Home',
    templateUrl: "partials/overview.html"
  } ).
  when( "/about", {
    title: 'About',
    templateUrl: "partials/about.html"
  } ).
  otherwise( {
    redirectTo: "/overview"
  } );
```

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about$ index.html
RewriteRule ^overview$ index.html
```